# Make GridView look like a textbox/savebutton

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
using SQL.Server.Management.Studio.2008.R2;
```

N00b here,

I have a GridView, but I want to make it look like a textbox/savebutton rather than a table with an edit/update lable next to it. I'm not really looking for "teh codez", but is this even possible? Is there a more practical way of doing this? Please help!
[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a GridView, but I want to make it look like a
>   textbox/savebutton rather than a table with an edit/update lable next
>   to it. I'm not really looking for "teh codez", but is this even
>   possible? Is there a more practical way of doing this? Please help!

Well, since you aren't looking for the code, let me just point you in the direction of `TemplateColumn` and `EditItemTemplate`. They should get you there.

You can put whatever controls you want inside a template column.